# 40.96.18.165 keeps visiting my web server

Tags: whois, web-crawler, malicious

Something/someone from 40.96.18.165 has been hitting my web server exactly eight times a day everyday since Feb 5, 2017.  The user agent used is Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0).

Look ups will show the IP address is from Microsoft.

Anything sinister going on?

Comment: The internet is full of background noise from scripts, bots and scanners, some malicious and some not, all running web requests and more. Without a more detailed traffic analyses I would guess that just a couple of HTTP requests are pretty harmless.

Comment: If you don't want this to happen, just block it at the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

It may be `bing` crawling your website to index it, as your IP is indeed in some Microsoft owned block.

But the real question is: why is it a problem for a given IP to come to your website 8 times a day? I doubt that this produce any kind of load or problems?

Just check if it is attempting some attacks (SQL injections, XSS, etc…) and if not, stop worrying about these accesses.